# SAS - datalines equivalent of MISSOVER / TRUNCOVER statement?

Tags: sas

I know for the infile statement, you can add a missover and truncover statement for missing values in the input, but if I'm using datalines for data instead of infile, is there an equivalent statement I can use?

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `infile` by following it with `datalines` and then `missover` or `truncover` etc.

```
data _null_;
infile datalines missover;
input a b c;
put _all_;
datalines;
1 2
3 4
;
run;
```